# iptables SNAT for UDP rule is only applied to some traffic

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, nat, udp

I want to use Source NAT to change the local IP address of UDP traffic. However, only locally-generated traffic has the NAT rule applied, replies to traffic generated from remote sources do not have the NAT applied.

Is locally-generated traffic different from replies to traffic from remote in a udp server?

I find a question from Redhat, but I can't access it...... The link is https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4427871

Environments:

- OS: Debian 11 x64
- iptables config

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.169.130 -p udp --sport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.169.129:10080
  ```
- [tcpdump results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz8o3.png), the first seven items applied the SNAT rule, however the following items didn't apply the SNAT rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux iptables NAT is applied to *conntrack states* rather than individual packets.

If conntrack is already tracking a flow (e.g. after it has received some inbound UDP packets), further packets matching that flow **won't touch the `nat` table at all** – they'll only have forward or reverse translations applied according to what's already in conntrack.

For example, if there was an outbound DNS query (which was SNATed to 193.299.181.993)<sup>1</sup>, `conntrack -L` might show a state like this, with its "reply-to" fields being used to match packets in the opposite direction:

| src | dst | sport | dport | reply-to src | reply-to dst <sup>1</sup> | r-to sport | r-to dport |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.1.124.56 | 83.171.22.22 | 39202 | 53 | 83.171.22.22 | 193.299.181.993 | 53 | 39202 |

So if your system sent some outbound packets *first,* they will match the iptables rule and get SNATed. But if conntrack thinks that the system sent those packets as a *reply* to non-DNATed inbound packets, then the outbound ones will not be checked against iptables `nat` rules.

Use the `conntrack` tool to verify this – for example, try deleting the matching states and see if NAT suddenly starts working.

If this turns out to be the problem, I can think of a few potential workarounds:

- Apply DNAT `--to-dest 192.168.169.129:10080` to inbound packets, then all matching outbound replies will be SNATed accordingly as well.
- Do something with `-j CT --notrack` flag, which prevents that packet from being stored as a conntrack state.
- Convert your ruleset to nftables, which has a more flexible chain/hook priority sstem, and where it is possible to apply *stateless* NAT by just setting the `ip saddr` field. (See [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429551/2168).) It may be possible to stack iptables and nftables on the same system.

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, that's supposed to be an *obviously* fake IP address.

Comment: It helps me a lot.  
I have made it work for UDP with `-j CT --notrack`.  
But I can't make it work for TCP. Can I setup a stateless SNAT for TCP with `-j CT --notrack` ?
Thanks!

Comment: This is my iptables rules: [rules image](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lpypl/picgo-repo/data/20220323015613.png)

Comment: TCP requires bidirectional communication. If you SNAT in one direction, you must equally DNAT in the other direction. (Normally conntrack would do that for you, but if you use `notrack` then you have to do it manually...) I would suggest using notrack _only_ for UDP, because with TCP it's already clear which side is initiating the connection.

Comment: Thanks. I have described my problem in detail at [iptables SNAT rules for TCP is only applied to some traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/1712341/iptables-snat-rules-for-tcp-is-only-applied-to-some-traffic). Could you give me some advice？

Comment: I have solved this problem with nftables. Maybe iptables is too difficult to setup. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Well, it's more that iptables actually doesn't have the same functionality that nftables does. It's not just a matter of NAT working differently between those two (stateful NAT works the same way in both), but also that nftables has truly stateless NAT as a completely new feature.